# Adding link to a clickable HTML image with a link that will redirect to another webpage using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, clickable-image

I don't know how to make an HTML image clickable. Also, using Javascript, I want to know how to make a clickable HTML image redirect to another webpage when clicked. For example:

[the HTML code of the image that I want to be clickable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pIYv.png)

Also, how to redirect to another webpage when the image is clicked. Like this:

[This, when this is clicked I want it to redirect us to another webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjwvX.png)

Can someone please help me, I will appreciate any answers.

I tried doing this:

```js
$('#imagefour').click(function() {
  window.location.href = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassination_Classroom";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/GY9FYJ-OG0I/maxresdefault.jpg" id="imagefour">
</a>
```

but nothing happened when I clicked the image, it didn't work. The school requires us to really use Javascript because it is the main goal of the project, thank you!!!

Comment: Take the JS away. Put the URL in the `href` attribute instead of using an empty value.

Comment: You can  do like this : ```<a href="link address"><img src="image source"></a>```

Comment: `<a href="">` is equivalent to linking to the page itself. Does the JS run if the page reloads?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Put the click function inside document.ready